# Playing Minecraft on Windows 10, owning a Xbox One disc

Tags: pc, xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I own a Minecraft disc for an Xbox One, and would like to play on my PC (ultimately, playing with others who will be on the Xbox).

I'm not too familiar with the Xbox account ecosystem, and with dozen different Minecraft editions, I'm lost as to how I can do that.

Comment: Have you looked at the microsoft/xbox store in windows 10? Sometimes if you've bought a game on the xbox it can appear here if you use the same account (I think?) Here's a list of compatible versions https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1274139-different-minecraft-editions

Comment: @Lemon The [tag:minecraft] tag belongs on this question, because the user would like to play on his PC, which would run Java Edition.

Comment: Well, he mentions Windows 10 specifically, and also says that he wants to use the existing Xbox One disc (that is a Bedrock Edition release)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to buy a separate copy of Minecraft for your computer. Xbox One games cannot be played on a computer, or on other video game consoles.

Comment: Might be worth adding that one can play Xbox One games on the PC using the "Game Streaming" feature on the Windows 10 Xbox app. However, that would only work if the user has an Xbox One console to begin with.