# Minecraft on pc/xbox

Tags: pc, xbox-app

So I play all my games with a pc, I do everything technology related on a pc. I don't use an xbox. I want to play games and stuff with my friends, who do use xbox, and thats mainly Minecraft. So I downloaded the xbox app, set everything up, but apparently to play minecraft I need a game pass, so my main question is, once I buy the gamepass, since I already have minecraft on my pc, do I have to buy it again on the xbox app, which is also on my pc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing Minecraft on Windows 10, owning a Xbox One disc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344534/playing-minecraft-on-windows-10-owning-a-xbox-one-disc). The duplicate poses the opposite situation, but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

To play cross platform with Xbox, you need to use [Minecraft for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/minecraft-for-windows-10/9nblggh2jhxj).

If you already own Minecraft Java edition, you should be able to log into mojang.net and redeem a Minecraft for Windows 10 edition key for free. From there you go to Windows store and redeem your key.

If you own the game, you don't need to subscribe to the gamepass service.